# In Selenium, how do I turn off logging?

Tags: selenium

I am using the following method:

```
set_browser_log_level 'off'
```

but my log level continues to include INFOs.

I am trying to suppress both logging and the "Last 4 commands" display for when my test enters a login password.

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/ruby/classes/Selenium/SeleniumDriver.html#M000128

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off logging in Selenium (from Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226519/turning-off-logging-in-selenium-from-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to switch to the latest version, even if it is called beta. These Selenium guys have strange version numbers. See if that helps.

Comment: I was already on 1.0-beta.  There's no release documentation yet for that version, hence why I'm linking to the latest available (0.9.2)