# How to disable logging using Selenium with Python binding

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Simple question: how to completely disable logging when using Selenium from Python bindings, ex code as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I've tried things like:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument('--log-level 3') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

or even:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.add_argument('--disable-logging') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

but still the file 'chromedriver.log' is appearing on each new run of the tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [source code](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py) of Chrome's webdriver, shows the existence of an option called `service_log_path`.

So if you want to get rid of the file, you could set this property to

- `/dev/null` if you are running under Linux/Unix ;
- `NUL` under windows

Hope it helps

Answer (score 25):

You may set `options.add_argument("--log-level=3")` for Chrome browser to be run with Selenuim, or you may set logging level to some higher level with:

```python
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # or any variant from ERROR, CRITICAL or NOTSET
```

But some messages will appear anyway in this case, including the starting DevTools message or SSL handshake error messages.

To run Chrome browser with Selenium in console in **completely silent mode**, you should use this snippet:

```python
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```

That trick will suppress any console message from either the Selenium driver or the browser itself, including the first message `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1` at the very start.

At the same time some runtime step-by-step data can be saved to *service log file*, in case its argument has been added.

Comment: What about Edgdriver?

Answer (score 13):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path='/dev/null')
```

Answer (score 7):

Just example for Windows people:

```
webdriver.Firefox(log_path='NUL')
```

Accepted answer is correct, but if you are new to Python / windows like i am, example like this will cut you few hours of google time.

Comment: I have not tested this, but I'm pretty sure you could use logpath=os.devnull and it will work independent of OS. (Need to import os, of course).

Comment: I _have_ tested this, and it works.  I was getting multi-gigabyte logs and it was killing our servers.  Now, nothing at all.  Thanks @codingatty

Comment: Not working in my machine (Manjaro latest). Tried both `os.devnull` and `NUL`. My code was this `driver = webdriver.Firefox(log_path=os.devnull, options=options, capabilities=capabilities, firefox_profile=profile)`

Answer (score 6):

To disable logging using *Selenium* and *Python* you need to add an experimental option through an instance of ***`ChromeOptions()`*** as follows:

```
add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

---

### Implementation

> [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) compatible code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

courtesy of:

https://joshuatz.com/posts/2020/selenium-webdriver-disabling-chrome-logging-messages/

Answer (score 1):

if you set service_log_path = None, it won't generate the geckodriver.log file:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service_log_path=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this is still the first thing that comes up when you search for a way to prevent logging from selenium and it did not get rid of the "dev listening" messages for me and I found a way that does:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service,options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find what logger is outputing the log to console then adjust it

`

```
    loggers = logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict

    # Print the names of all the loggers
    for name in loggers:
        print(name)
    logging.getLogger('urllib3.connectionpool').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

`