# How to execute Selenium Chrome WebDriver in silent mode?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When using Chrome Selenium WebDriver, it  will output diagnostic output when the servers are started:

> Started ChromeDriver (v2.0) on port 9515

I do not want to see these messages, how can I suppress them?

I do this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--silent");
IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But diagnostic output is not suppress.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47496386/551744

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable logging using Selenium with Python binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613869/how-to-disable-logging-using-selenium-with-python-binding)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I simply do this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: holy crap, finally, after two years someone actually posts how to fix this stupid problem that shouldn't be a problem. Thank you very much. For reference, the ruby equivalent of this is `@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome , switches: %w[--log-level=3]`

Comment: This solution did not work for me, though Yi Zeng's solution did.

Comment: **OMG!** This works for me even with Python in Debian 10.

Comment: How do you do that with Python?

Comment: @Menachem chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)

Answer (score 17):

Good question, however, I don't know where you got that `.AddArgument("--silent");` thing, as that's Chrome's command line switch, not for ChromeDriver. Also, there isn't a Chrome switch called `--silent` anyway.

Under `OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome` namespace, there is class called `ChromeDriverService` which has a property `SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation` defaults to false. Basically what you might want to do is to create
`ChromeDriverService` and pass it into ChromeDriver's constructor. Please refer to the documentation [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html).

Here is the C# code that suppresses ChromeDriver's diagnostics outputs.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

**EDIT:**
ChromeDriver (not Chrome) has a command line argument `--silent`, which is supposed to work. `SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation` in .NET binding does exactly that. However, it seems only suppress some of the messages.

Here is a closed chromedriver ticket: 
[Issue 116: How to disable the diagnostic messages and log file from Chrome Driver?](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=116)

Comment: Thank's four your help. with your code  the Output  _Started ChromeDriver (v2.0) on port 9515_ is not display.
But output similar to below appears: 

`[5468:8996:0404/150758:ERROR:textfield.h(156)] NOT IMPLEMENTED`
Is it possible to remove this output ?

Comment: @PapyRef: It depends on how ChromeDriver is designed. If this message is also diagnostics message, then this is a bug, please report it. However, if this is not diagnostics message, then you can only ask for a feature request to suppress this as well. I don't know which does this belong to.

Comment: is it can be implemented too in Selenium 3 @YiZeng ?

Comment: This works like a charm, however why are you using the options variable? I tried without it and it works fine.

Comment: @KingMak: Selenium API has long changed since then. I guess `ChromeOptions` was required when initializing `ChromeDriver` with service.

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but I also needed to add `chrome.AddExcludedArgument("enable-logging");` to suppress the [following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392423/python-selenium-devtools-listening-on-ws-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 12):

For me no one of previous answers did not help , my solution was:

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverLocation);
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - HideCommandPromptWindow says it all

Answer (score 8):

For me the only thing that worked for

> ```
>    selenium-chrome-driver-2.48.2.jar
>    chromedriver 2.20
>    selenium-java-2.48.2.jar
> ```

was

> ```
>    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
>    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
>    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
>    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
> ```

Answer (score 7):

**try this code it will hide browser with "headless" Argument but Chrome ver should > 58**

( and even you can hide command prompt window )

```
    IWebDriver driver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("test-type");
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("--headless");//hide browser

ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"chromedriverExepath\");
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
//service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;//even we can hide command prompt window (with un comment this line)  
options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding themselves here wanting a Java solution, there is a thread here:

[Selenium chromedriver disable logging or redirect it java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975287/selenium-chromedriver-disable-logging-or-redirect-it-java)

Answer (score 1):

only add below line
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");

output:-
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jun 28, 2022 10:38:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
public static IWebDriver Driver { set; get; }
-----
Driver = CreateBrowserDriver();

////////////// Create Driver
private static IWebDriver CreateBrowserDriver()
{
    try
    {
        var options = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArgument("--headless"); // HIDE Chrome Browser
        var service = OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true; // HIDE Chrome Driver
        service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;

        return new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(service, options);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Please install Google Chrome.");
    }
}
////////////// Exit Driver
public static void ExitDriver()
{
    if (Driver != null)
    {
        Driver.Quit();
    }

    Driver = null;

    try
    {
        // Chrome
        System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver").ToList().ForEach(px => px.Kill());
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To run Chrome browser with Selenium in console in **completely silent mode**, you should use this snippet:

```python
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```

That trick will suppress any console message from either the Selenium driver or the browser itself, including the first message `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1` at the very start.