# How to disable ChromeDriver console messages?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testautomationfx

I'm using chrome driver as my web driver to test my site. I just need to know is there any way to disable the default messages that we are getting at the time of running the chrome driver. e.g.

```
[0.996][INFO]: received WebDriver request: GET /status 
[0.996][INFO]: sending WebDriver response: 200 {
   "sessionId": "",
   "status": 0,
```

All I need to see the output only in the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute Selenium Chrome WebDriver in silent mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702533/how-to-execute-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-silent-mode)

Answer (score 0):

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Change the level as needed to achieve your desired output.