# Java Selenium Chrome driver - Disable logging

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with Selenium Chrome driver and want to disable logging, I'v tried all existing solutions including :

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--log-level=3");
```

and

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.verbose", false);
```

but none worked for me, still having this Info and warning log showing up :

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e) on port 17965 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Jul 25, 2017 7:01:16 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the
>   remote end Jul 25, 2017 7:01:16 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS

Answer (score 8):

This is what I have been doing and it has worked so far for me.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArgument("--log-level=3");
chromeOptions.addArgument("--silent");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: How does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519284/8020699) solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

For Minimum output you can use the below code -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `--log-level=3` works for me, tested on:
`Ruby, watir, selenium 3.142.3, chromedriver 75.0.3770.140 , win 10`

Ruby code:

```
   options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

    default_options = %w[--log-level=3]
    default_options.each do |option|
      options.add_argument(option)
    end

    @driver = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: options
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `chromedriver --help` it states if you want to turn logging off, you need to add argument "--silent" (log nothing (equivalent to --log-level=OFF)
in other words:

```
chromeOptions.addArgument("--silent");
```