# Selenium ChromeDriver how to disable the message:"DevTools on ws

Tags: c#, selenium, console-application, selenium-chromedriver

So I am creating a bot with chrome headless browser and it works just fine. I had quite a lot warnings so I disabled them after reasearch with those commands:

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
        option.AddArgument("--headless");
        option.AddArgument("--silent");
        option.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
        option.AddArgument("--log-level=3");


        ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;


        _driver = new ChromeDriver(service, option);
```

But there is one more message showing when programs starts:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12015/devtools/browser/6b70a3c5-56c8-4c90-952a-d0e0ef254ddf
```

Any idea how to disable it from showing?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible via the [driver](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/devtools/devtools_http_handler.cc?type=cs&l=230). You could override the stdout by either running the code in a separate thread or by overriding the [service](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/DriverService.cs#L230) and by setting [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are trying to fix Selenium with Python on Windows, type:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

with the experimental_option line being the special sauce.

Comment: This worked for me (python 3.8 on windows 10 with selenium 3.141.59).

Comment: can you please post a full solution? I keep getting the same message at the beginning when I launch the webdriver

Comment: @DarkLeader, all I can think of is that you didn't send the experimental option to Chrome. This is done with the line `browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`. If you are still stuck, you could email me your program at admin@lifeboat.com with the subject "Lifeboat Foundation DarkLeader".

Comment: this is what i used: options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(). and then everything is the same.

Comment: @Darkleader, I changed my answer to include `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options` which my program uses.

Comment: This worked for me (python 3.10.0 on windows 11 Pro with selenium 4.1.0)

Answer (score 12):

That did the trick

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;         
Driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add following two options .

```
option.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
option.AddArgument("test-type");
```