# Stop Chrome in headless mode from logging

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Python/Selenium/ChromeDriver/Chrome to scrape a website and it works fine but, especially in headless mode, I'm getting lots of logs such as those below.  How do I stop these?

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1...
[0323/120327.827:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The SSL certificate used to load... 
[0323/120330.441:WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2921)] Received HEADERS for invalid...
[0323/120353.366:WARNING:render_frame_host_impl.cc(2750)] OnDidStopLoading was called twice.
[0323/120356.054:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to execute script from...
```

Comment: If by code trials you mean 'what have I tried'...
- There is a 'silent mode' option that I can give to the chromedriver, but this doesn't seem to help which makes me suspect this is Selenium not the Chromedriver, but I might be wrong
- I've also tried the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226519/turning-off-logging-in-selenium-from-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47751529/how-do-i-suppress-console-cmd-error-messages-in-python