# Selenium chromedriver disable logging or redirect it java

Tags: java, selenium, logging, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium in a mini web crawler to get the page source. My output log is invaded by selenium logs, is there a way to totally disable the logging or just redirect it in someway to /dev/null?

The logging messages are these:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600233 
(523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d) on port 1628
Only local connections are allowed.
ott 24, 2018 7:52:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMAZIONI: Detected dialect: OSS
```

I am calling the driver in the following way:

```
WebDriver driver = null;
            try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.setBinary("/usr/bin/chromium");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--silent");
            chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
            /*FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
            firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
            System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
            System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/dev/null");


            FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);*/
            if(driver!=null) {
            driver.get(link);
```

Comment: may be you should look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702533/how-to-execute-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-silent-mode)

Comment: Ok it is possible to get rid of:
`Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600233 
(523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d) on port 1628
Only local connections are allowed.`
Using:
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");`
But `ott 24, 2018 7:52:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMAZIONI: Detected dialect: OSS` is still there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok i have managed to finally get rid of that useless loggings. Here is what i did.

Use:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");`

To get rid of chromedriver logs:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600233
>   (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d) on port 1628 Only local
>   connections are allowed.

And use:
`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);`

To get rid of selenium logs:

> ott 24, 2018 7:52:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFORMAZIONI: Detected dialect: OSS

Comment: Why are these useless? You start having issues and probably the first thing you are going to do is to turn those back on... Just ignore them.

Comment: @JeffC any logging that is not requested or error/warning is going to spam the reader with so much garbage they won't notice an issue when it does occur. And The UNIX philosophy agrees; good command line tools have no output on success.

Comment: You shouldn't be looking at console output for test run results. You should be using a test runner framework like TestNG or JUnit to run your tests and get results. Better yet use a plugin for Jenkins (or whatever) that pulls those TestNG, etc. results into a report to make it even cleaner, have a history, etc.

Comment: lots of "ChromeDriver was started successfully."  messages from v83 ... see my response below

Comment: There seems to be a solution for the `ChromeDriver was started successfully` thing, but I'm not really liking it. https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/QipZrjyoEgg

Answer (score 8):

Drunk Cat's answer is right and very useful to get rid of 100's of pointless info messages in a log.  Maybe use `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);` 
to catch errors (Level.SEVERE instead of Level.OFF)

**Chromedriver v83 (2020 Update)**
Note that an alternate to setting the property:

```
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
```

is something like this:

```
DriverService.Builder serviceBuilder = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().withSilent(true);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// ... addArguments to options ....
ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = (ChromeDriverService)serviceBuilder.build(); 
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

However, for whatever reason neither `.withSilent(true)` or setting the property work on Chromedriver v83 (confirmed on Linux  and Windows).  I needed to add a line of code to re-direct output:

```
:
ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = (ChromeDriverService)serviceBuilder.build(); 
chromeDriverService.sendOutputTo(new FileOutputStream("/dev/null"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

You could just substitute "/dev/nul" with a real file if you wanted  (for debugging, etc).  Or a platform independent way of dealing with null output that works with Java 8+ :

```
chromeDriverService.sendOutputTo(new OutputStream(){@Override public void write(int b){}});
```

My guess is that this may be a bug in the v83 release, but at least it got me to find another way of re-directing or shutting off chromedriver logging.

Comment: MetalRules - yours is the only answer which actually works, with Chrome 91.