# Java code to stop seeing detailed logs in ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Can someone share a code which stops ChromeDriver to display logs in console. These red color logs are taking lots of space.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Mr. USA, you want to elaborate a little more what you need. Provide a small sample of your code, the output you get and the output you want. Share what you tried. You will find SO quite helpful when asking with complete context

Comment: See my and drunk cat's responses in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975287/selenium-chromedriver-disable-logging-or-redirect-it-java.

You should be able to get rid of both the selenium and chromedriver output with those steps.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the code below helps you to get rid of those red-coloured 'logs':

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");        
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```