# Disable console output of webdriver using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a python program that uses Selenium and Chrome to analyze data from some websites. The problem I'm having is that either Selenium or the Webdriver is flooding the console with output I don't care about and making it difficult to view my programs output. I've read many other threads about this with various driver options, but nothing seems to work. The best these options do is remove this:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54429/devtools/browser/bbc7bc4a-bdf2-43a3-9fd4-c94dd9113aea
```

But all of these remain:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:54462/session/7950e584b7a2cd732bdd5bf9bb685178/execute/sync {"script": "return (function(){return function(){var d=this;function f(a){return\"string\"==typeof a};function h(a,b){this.code=a;this.a=l[a]||m;this.message=b||\"\";a=this.a.replace(/((?:^|\\s+)[a-z])/g,function(a){return a.toUpperCase().replace(/^[\\s\\xa0]+/g,\"\")});b=a.length-5;if(0>b||a.indexOf(\"Error\",b)!=b)a+=\"Error\";this.name=a;a=Error(this.message);a.name=this.name;this.stack=a.stack||\"\"}\n(function(){var a=Error;function b(){}b.prototype=a.prototype;h.b=a.prototype;h.prototype=new b;h.prototype.constructor=h;h.a=function(b,c,g){for(var e=Array(arguments.length-2),k=2;k<arguments.length;k++)e[k-2]=arguments[k];return a.prototype[c].apply(b,e)}})();var m=\"unknown error\",l={15:\"element not selectable\",11:\"element not visible\"};l[31]=m;l[30]=m;l[24]=\"invalid cookie domain\";l[29]=\"invalid element coordinates\";l[12]=\"invalid element state\";l[32]=\"invalid selector\";l[51]=\"invalid selector\";\nl[52]=\"invalid selector\";l[17]=\"javascript error\";l[405]=\"unsupported operation\";l[34]=\"move target out of bounds\";l[27]=\"no such alert\";l[7]=\"no such element\";l[8]=\"no such frame\";l[23]=\"no such window\";l[28]=\"script timeout\";l[33]=\"session not created\";l[10]=\"stale element reference\";l[21]=\"timeout\";l[25]=\"unable to set cookie\";l[26]=\"unexpected alert open\";l[13]=m;l[9]=\"unknown command\";h.prototype.toString=function(){return this.name+\": \"+this.message};var n;a:{var p=d.navigator;if(p){var q=p.userAgent;if(q){n=q;break a}}n=\"\"}function r(a){return-1!=n.indexOf(a)};function t(a,b){for(var e=a.length,c=f(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,g=0;g<e;g++)g in c&&b.call(void 0,c[g],g,a)};function v(){return r(\"iPhone\")&&!r(\"iPod\")&&!r(\"iPad\")};function w(){return(r(\"Chrome\")||r(\"CriOS\"))&&!r(\"Edge\")};var x=r(\"Opera\"),y=r(\"Trident\")||r(\"MSIE\"),z=r(\"Edge\"),A=r(\"Gecko\")&&!(-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!r(\"Edge\"))&&!(r(\"Trident\")||r(\"MSIE\"))&&!r(\"Edge\"),aa=-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!r(\"Edge\");function B(){var a=d.document;return a?a.documentMode:void 0}var C;\na:{var D=\"\",E=function(){var a=n;if(A)return/rv\\:([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(z)return/Edge\\/([\\d\\.]+)/.exec(a);if(y)return/\\b(?:MSIE|rv)[: ]([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(aa)return/WebKit\\/(\\S+)/.exec(a);if(x)return/(?:Version)[ \\/]?(\\S+)/.exec(a)}();E&&(D=E?E[1]:\"\");if(y){var F=B();if(null!=F&&F>parseFloat(D)){C=String(F);break a}}C=D}var G;var H=d.document;G=H&&y?B()||(\"CSS1Compat\"==H.compatMode?parseInt(C,10):5):void 0;var ba=r(\"Firefox\"),ca=v()||r(\"iPod\"),da=r(\"iPad\"),I=r(\"Android\")&&!(w()||r(\"Firefox\")||r(\"Opera\")||r(\"Silk\")),ea=w(),J=r(\"Safari\")&&!(w()||r(\"Coast\")||r(\"Opera\")||r(\"Edge\")||r(\"Silk\")||r(\"Android\"))&&!(v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\"));function K(a){return(a=a.exec(n))?a[1]:\"\"}(function(){if(ba)return K(/Firefox\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(y||z||x)return C;if(ea)return v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\")?K(/CriOS\\/([0-9.]+)/):K(/Chrome\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(J&&!(v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\")))return K(/Version\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(ca||da){var a=/Version\\/(\\S+).*Mobile\\/(\\S+)/.exec(n);if(a)return a[1]+\".\"+a[2]}else if(I)return(a=K(/Android\\s+([0-9.]+)/))?a:K(/Version\\/([0-9.]+)/);return\"\"})();var L,M=function(){if(!A)return!1;var a=d.Components;if(!a)return!1;try{if(!a.classes)return!1}catch(g){return!1}var b=a.classes,a=a.interfaces,e=b[\"@mozilla.org/xpcom/version-comparator;1\"].getService(a.nsIVersionComparator),c=b[\"@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1\"].getService(a.nsIXULAppInfo).version;L=function(a){e.compare(c,\"\"+a)};return!0}(),N=y&&!(8<=Number(G)),fa=y&&!(9<=Number(G));I&&M&&L(2.3);I&&M&&L(4);J&&M&&L(6);var ga={SCRIPT:1,STYLE:1,HEAD:1,IFRAME:1,OBJECT:1},O={IMG:\" \",BR:\"\\n\"};function P(a,b,e){if(!(a.nodeName in ga))if(3==a.nodeType)e?b.push(String(a.nodeValue).replace(/(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/g,\"\")):b.push(a.nodeValue);else if(a.nodeName in O)b.push(O[a.nodeName]);else for(a=a.firstChild;a;)P(a,b,e),a=a.nextSibling};function Q(a,b){b=b.toLowerCase();return\"style\"==b?ha(a.style.cssText):N&&\"value\"==b&&R(a,\"INPUT\")?a.value:fa&&!0===a[b]?String(a.getAttribute(b)):(a=a.getAttributeNode(b))&&a.specified?a.value:null}var ia=/[;]+(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(?:[^()]*\\([^()]*\\))*[^()]*$)/;\nfunction ha(a){var b=[];t(a.split(ia),function(a){var c=a.indexOf(\":\");0<c&&(a=[a.slice(0,c),a.slice(c+1)],2==a.length&&b.push(a[0].toLowerCase(),\":\",a[1],\";\"))});b=b.join(\"\");return b=\";\"==b.charAt(b.length-1)?b:b+\";\"}function S(a,b){N&&\"value\"==b&&R(a,\"OPTION\")&&null===Q(a,\"value\")?(b=[],P(a,b,!1),a=b.join(\"\")):a=a[b];return a}function R(a,b){b&&\"string\"!==typeof b&&(b=b.toString());return!!a&&1==a.nodeType&&(!b||a.tagName.toUpperCase()==b)}\nfunction T(a){return R(a,\"OPTION\")?!0:R(a,\"INPUT\")?(a=a.type.toLowerCase(),\"checkbox\"==a||\"radio\"==a):!1};var ja={\"class\":\"className\",readonly:\"readOnly\"},U=\"allowfullscreen allowpaymentrequest allowusermedia async autofocus autoplay checked compact complete controls declare default defaultchecked defaultselected defer disabled ended formnovalidate hidden indeterminate iscontenteditable ismap itemscope loop multiple muted nohref nomodule noresize noshade novalidate nowrap open paused playsinline pubdate readonly required reversed scoped seamless seeking selected truespeed typemustmatch willvalidate\".split(\" \");function V(a,b){var e=null,c=b.toLowerCase();if(\"style\"==c)return(e=a.style)&&!f(e)&&(e=e.cssText),e;if((\"selected\"==c||\"checked\"==c)&&T(a)){if(!T(a))throw new h(15,\"Element is not selectable\");b=\"selected\";e=a.type&&a.type.toLowerCase();if(\"checkbox\"==e||\"radio\"==e)b=\"checked\";return S(a,b)?\"true\":null}var g=R(a,\"A\");if(R(a,\"IMG\")&&\"src\"==c||g&&\"href\"==c)return(e=Q(a,c))&&(e=S(a,c)),e;if(\"spellcheck\"==c){e=Q(a,c);if(null!==e){if(\"false\"==e.toLowerCase())return\"false\";if(\"true\"==e.toLowerCase())return\"true\"}return S(a,\nc)+\"\"}g=ja[b]||b;a:if(f(U))c=f(c)&&1==c.length?U.indexOf(c,0):-1;else{for(var u=0;u<U.length;u++)if(u in U&&U[u]===c){c=u;break a}c=-1}if(0<=c)return(e=null!==Q(a,b)||S(a,g))?\"true\":null;try{var k=S(a,g)}catch(ka){}(c=null==k)||(c=typeof k,c=\"object\"==c&&null!=k||\"function\"==c);c?e=Q(a,b):e=k;return null!=e?e.toString():null}var W=[\"_\"],X=d;W[0]in X||!X.execScript||X.execScript(\"var \"+W[0]);\nfor(var Y;W.length&&(Y=W.shift());){var Z;if(Z=!W.length)Z=void 0!==V;Z?X[Y]=V:X[Y]&&X[Y]!==Object.prototype[Y]?X=X[Y]:X=X[Y]={}};; return this._.apply(null,arguments);}.apply({navigator:typeof window!='undefined'?window.navigator:null,document:typeof window!='undefined'?window.document:null}, arguments);}\n).apply(null, arguments);", "args": [{"ELEMENT": "2465811d-f63e-45e9-97d4-8939dd73bd7d", "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "2465811d-f63e-45e9-97d4-8939dd73bd7d"}, "href"]}
http://127.0.0.1:54462 "POST /session/7950e584b7a2cd732bdd5bf9bb685178/execute/sync HTTP/1.1" 200 127
```

Is there any way to get these removed as well? Here is my setup for the webdriver (I've tried enabling/disabling many combinations of these options in case something is conflicting, but that didn't help):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chrome_path
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1400x1080")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,
                                desired_capabilities=capa,
                                executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```

Here are my versions:

```
python: 3.8.2
selenium: 3.141.0
chrome: 83.0.4103.61
chromedriver: 83.0.4103.39
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue as described, using all of the same versions except for Python, which I tested against 3.8.3 (x64) - I was able to remove all debugging from just excluding the `enable-logging` switch. Have you tried this on another machine?

Comment: I haven't yet, but I'll test it on another comp today. Thanks for confirming the settings worked with these versions, now I'll need to check what it is about my system that's allowing all that output to go through

Comment: @Lucan I just tried on a fresh machine that I recently formatted and installed windows 10 and I get the same behavior. All the POST/GET output is still coming through. I'll check if there're some other settings in my repo that might be causing this.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? I spun up a quick web server with a test page sending multiple post requests and still nothing.

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61289528/3190953)

Answer (score 28):

this worked for me
`chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")`

another answer suggested using "--log-level=OFF" however this didn't seem to work for me

Comment: Valids levels are `INFO = 0`,   `WARNING = 1`,   `LOG_ERROR = 2`,  `LOG_FATAL = 3`. Source is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866124/4116924)

Answer (score 4):

You can send all logs to the void, [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613869/how-to-disable-logging-using-selenium-with-python-binding)

```py
import os

# Let python handle it
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path=os.devnull)
# The proper null device option for Windows
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path='NUL')
```

, or use the less documented 'silent mode' explained [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/34572)

```py
options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
```

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: `options.add_argument("--log-level=0")` did the trick for me! Kudos to you!

Answer (score 0):

import selenium logger

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
import logging

LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following method and it works:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 0):

Mute the driver service:

```
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
service = ChromeService()
service.creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
```