# Selenium Edge Driver Silent Mode

Tags: python, selenium

I currently have a working python script leveraging Selenium driver for Edge browser. I need this script to run as job but due to security setting SQL Agent and Windows agent cant open the browser to scrape webpage. I would need script to run in silent mode without opening the edge browser window.

This article seems to be what I need but it is chrome.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137334/disable-console-output-of-webdriver-using-selenium-in-python
```

I dont post script because the connections and data in script have connections to a private company intranet site.

Comment: Which exact feature are you looking as in Silent Mode as per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137334/disable-console-output-of-webdriver-using-selenium-in-python)

Comment: Yes for edge I need this to execute with out opening a browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--headless");
```

You can also hide the driver console window:

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--no-default-browser-check");
var chromeDriverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var driver = new EdgeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```