# Selenium can't silence output

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently running an application that opens Netflix, enters my login details then logs in. However when I run the program using I keep getting this:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on port 57276
Only local connections are allowed.
```

I've tried --log-level=3, still doesn't work.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702533/how-to-execute-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-silent-mode). There are several ways to solve this problem.

Comment: None of those methods work.