# How to hide Selenium Output

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies

I created a selenium program that scrapes some info from my website and I am using Chrome headless as the webdriver. Now, whenever I scrape the data, it shows this message:

> [0510/170058.841:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://accounts.google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://www.mywebsite.com/ (0)
>   [0510/170059.254:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://blogger.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.", source: https://www.mywebsite.com/ (0)

Note: The "source: " in this message is not the actual one. I have changed it just for a reference.

Now I know this isn't an error and the program works as it should. But, I want to hide this message because it makes a huge mess when printing the output.

Comment: You can't. You simply can't. This happened with me also a month ago. You should just ignore it...

Answer (score 1):

I use: `.add_argument('--log-level=3')` but this might suppress other messages you do want. Credit to this original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20748376/11277108