# Hide WDM ChromeDriverManager WebDriver manager in console

Tags: python, selenium

I have searched for this topic of how to hide in the console such part

```
[WDM] -

[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 94.0.4606
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 94.0.4606
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\Future\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\94.0.4606.61\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

This is related to installing `ChromeDriverManager`.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the logging level using the `log_level` argument of the `ChromeDriverManager` class using:

```
CRITICAL = 50    
FATAL = CRITICAL    
ERROR = 40    
WARNING = 30    
WARN = WARNING    
INFO = 20    
DEBUG = 10    
NOTSET = 0
```

For example, to disable absolutely all logging:

```
ChromeDriverManager(log_level=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If like me none of the solutions work for you, [steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76486880/14004940) might help.

Basically you need to manually set the loggers levels for different loggers.
To find out logger names, following is the code:

```
import logging

loggers = logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict
for name in loggers:
    print(name)
```

This will give you a list of loggers like: `WDM`, `urllib3.connection`, `selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection`, etc.

Now you need to set their logging levels manually:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('WDM').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('urllib3.connectionpool').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

**HTH**