# How to stop selenium from printing WebDriver manager startup logs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, logging, webdrivermanager-python

When I'm launching a new selenium driver I get a message as:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current chromium version is 90.0.4430
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 90.0.4430 chromium
Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver] found in cache
```

I tryed using:

```py
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
chrome_options.add_argument('log-level=2')
```

But none worked.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77632392/14004940) answer?

Answer (score 3):

according to [documents](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/):
just add below code into your files:

```
import os
os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0'
```

i have tried it with myself, working very well

Answer (score 2):

To silent [webdrivermanager-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421086/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-webdriver-manager-error-even-after-instal) logs and remove them from console, you can initialize the env variable ***WDM_LOG_LEVEL*** with ***`0`*** value before your selenium tests as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os

os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `log-level` that you are setting for `chrome_options` is completely separate from the logs that you are seeing from using the external library [webdrivermanager](https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/) for Python. That library will have its own way of disabling log messages (or at least it should). There are other Python libraries for managing WebDriver installs, such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) for example. Related, you might be able to change the Python logging level to hide that message, see [Dynamically changing log level without restarting the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617355/dynamically-changing-log-level-without-restarting-the-application) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using web driver manager? it looks like that is what is giving you logs (pip install webdriver-manager) . Im using selenium without web driver manager or adding any chrome options to remove logs , and not getting any logs printed.

also see :[Turning off logging in Selenium (from Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226519/turning-off-logging-in-selenium-from-python/21688906#21688906)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for webdriver_manager v3.8.3:

```
from webdriver_manager.core.logger import __logger as wdm_logger
wdm_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```