# How can I disable the python selenium logs?

Tags: python, selenium

How can i diseble the seleniuum logs?
I tried :

```
import logging
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path='/dev/null')
```

```
chromedriver --log-level=OFF
```

Any of this worked for me

Comment: Do any of the answers in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613869/how-to-disable-logging-using-selenium-with-python-binding) solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this code snippet solve your problem?

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
```