# I don't want to output information in terminal with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, terminal

I do not want to receive outputs related to selenium while the project is running. Is there any way to prevent this? An example below

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgdTo.png)

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text. Post [mre] of your code and explain what do you expect and how it is different from what you get.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613869/how-to-disable-logging-using-selenium-with-python-binding

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MSH Thank you so much. that's exactly what i wanted. Sorry if I asked the question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your question its a little bit confused. You can run your code inside a gui or something.