# How do I reduce the verbosity of chromedriver logs when running it under selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

My jenkins failure reports for my functional tests are full of lines like this:

```
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: DEBUG: Finished Request
selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:52932/session/60d406aa8e55ac841cf4efb4a43e63be/element {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "60d406aa8e55ac841cf4efb4a43e63be", "value": "#Login input[name=email]"}
```

I don't care about them and there are hundreds of these lines of output for every line of stacktrace that I actually want to see. How do I turn them off?

Things I have tried so far that don't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service_args=['--silent'], 
    service_log_path='/tmp/throwaway.log')
```

And...

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service_args=['2>/dev/null'])
```

And...

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service_args=['>', '/dev/null', '2>&1'])
```

All without reducing any of the output.

Comment: Does [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21688906/771848) help?

Comment: Yup, that works perfectly. Why don't you add it as an answer or link it through or something and I'll award you the bounty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the [`logging level`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels) on the `remote_connection` higher than `DEBUG`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER, logging
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

FYI, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688906/771848).

Comment: how do i do that for local?(Not remote_connection) Is it possible?

Comment: This should work locally:

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)