# Selenium standalone server log level

Tags: python, security, selenium, logging, monitoring

Long story short: I'm trying to change log level to WARNING on selenium standalone server. I'm running 2.48.2 on CentOS 6.7.

I tried the server side, i.e. added `-Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING` when starting the server - didn't work. Then I tried custom properties file `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/selenium/my.properties` with default level as WARNING - didn't work.

Then I tried doing that on the client side, I'm using WebDriver API for python. I tried both suggestions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226519/turning-off-logging-in-selenium-from-python), didn't work either.

Is there a nice non-hacky way to change the level to Warning? Or at least make it omit the keystrokes? It's dumping passwords in my log files and I don't like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING` is correct. You need to add it in front of `-jar`.

Comment: Thanks. The hint about putting the options before `-jar` was valuable! I finally managed to get output to file instead of Windows cmd shell by using `java -Dselenium.LOGGER=selenium.log -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar`.