# Turn off 'POST'/'GET' log entries from chromedriver

Tags: python, logging, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Currently I am using 'logging' module for chromedriver

Chrome initialization parameters are:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
options.add_argument("--silent")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./resources/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```

I tried the above arguments in hopes that would get rid of the 'POST' and 'GET' logs I keep seeing.
Example of stuff I want to get rid of but have no clue what turns these off:

```
2018-01-30 17:35:41,871 : DEBUG:GET http://127.0.0.1:62516/session/37f7905cb48936e8dea1926aa119afcd/element/0.7136428266323058-2/displayed {"id": "0.7136428266323058-2", "sessionId": "37f7905cb48936e8dea1926aa119afcd"}
2018-01-30 17:35:41,886 : DEBUG:Finished Request
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a few hours of doing searches and it not working finally found the relevant SO answer:
[Turning off logging in Selenium (from Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226519/turning-off-logging-in-selenium-from-python/21688906#21688906)

Additional item I needed to do is this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```