# Console is getting flooded with DEBUG messages once click() method is invoked through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, log-level

I'm using selenium firefox and my code below generate what i needed but after it finished loading it generated a flooded of debugging messages. What am I doing wrong?

```
    def count_list(self, busienss_seller_url):
    seller_url = busienss_seller_url
    driver.get(seller_url)
    while True:
        load_content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/button')
        try:
            load_content.click()
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            print('Finish loading...')
            break
    links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title-link")
    number_of_links = []
    for link in links:
        ad_links = link.get_attribute('href')
        number_of_links.append(ad_links)
    driver.close()
    'count ads - return how many links are in the list'
    return len(number_of_links)
```

The debugging message is below gets generated x100+, have a look at 2018-09-04 22:36:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST which loaded a bunch of javascript. How do I fix it or can I just ignore it?

```
2018-09-04 22:36:57 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:50910 "POST /session/7229021d-dce2-4653-bea9-7cd29732d83a/execute/sync HTTP/1.1" 200 114
2018-09-04 22:36:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2018-09-04 22:36:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:50910/session/7229021d-dce2-4653-bea9-7cd29732d83a/execute/sync {"script": "return (function(){return function(){var d=this;function f(a){return\"string\"==typeof a};function h(a,b){this.code=a;this.a=l[a]||m;this.message=b||\"\";a=this.a.replace(/((?:^|\\s+)[a-z])/g,function(a){return a.toUpperCase().replace(/^[\\s\\xa0]+/g,\"\")});b=a.length-5;if(0>b||a.indexOf(\"Error\",b)!=b)a+=\"Error\";this.name=a;a=Error(this.message);a.name=this.name;this.stack=a.stack||\"\"}\n(function(){var a=Error;function b(){}b.prototype=a.prototype;h.b=a.prototype;h.prototype=new b;h.prototype.constructor=h;h.a=function(b,c,g){for(var e=Array(arguments.length-2),k=2;k<arguments.length;k++)e[k-2]=arguments[k];return a.prototype[c].apply(b,e)}})();var m=\"unknown error\",l={15:\"element not selectable\",11:\"element not visible\"};l[31]=m;l[30]=m;l[24]=\"invalid cookie domain\";l[29]=\"invalid element coordinates\";l[12]=\"invalid element state\";l[32]=\"invalid selector\";l[51]=\"invalid selector\";\nl[52]=\"invalid selector\";l[17]=\"javascript error\";l[405]=\"unsupported operation\";l[34]=\"move target out of bounds\";l[27]=\"no such alert\";l[7]=\"no such element\";l[8]=\"no such frame\";l[23]=\"no such window\";l[28]=\"script timeout\";l[33]=\"session not created\";l[10]=\"stale element reference\";l[21]=\"timeout\";l[25]=\"unable to set cookie\";l[26]=\"unexpected alert open\";l[13]=m;l[9]=\"unknown command\";h.prototype.toString=function(){return this.name+\": \"+this.message};var n;a:{var p=d.navigator;if(p){var q=p.userAgent;if(q){n=q;break a}}n=\"\"}function r(a){return-1!=n.indexOf(a)};function t(a,b){for(var e=a.length,c=f(a)?a.split(\"\"):a,g=0;g<e;g++)g in c&&b.call(void 0,c[g],g,a)};function v(){return r(\"iPhone\")&&!r(\"iPod\")&&!r(\"iPad\")};function w(){return(r(\"Chrome\")||r(\"CriOS\"))&&!r(\"Edge\")};var x=r(\"Opera\"),y=r(\"Trident\")||r(\"MSIE\"),z=r(\"Edge\"),A=r(\"Gecko\")&&!(-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!r(\"Edge\"))&&!(r(\"Trident\")||r(\"MSIE\"))&&!r(\"Edge\"),aa=-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf(\"webkit\")&&!r(\"Edge\");function B(){var a=d.document;return a?a.documentMode:void 0}var C;\na:{var D=\"\",E=function(){var a=n;if(A)return/rv\\:([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(z)return/Edge\\/([\\d\\.]+)/.exec(a);if(y)return/\\b(?:MSIE|rv)[: ]([^\\);]+)(\\)|;)/.exec(a);if(aa)return/WebKit\\/(\\S+)/.exec(a);if(x)return/(?:Version)[ \\/]?(\\S+)/.exec(a)}();E&&(D=E?E[1]:\"\");if(y){var F=B();if(null!=F&&F>parseFloat(D)){C=String(F);break a}}C=D}var G;var H=d.document;G=H&&y?B()||(\"CSS1Compat\"==H.compatMode?parseInt(C,10):5):void 0;var ba=r(\"Firefox\"),ca=v()||r(\"iPod\"),da=r(\"iPad\"),I=r(\"Android\")&&!(w()||r(\"Firefox\")||r(\"Opera\")||r(\"Silk\")),ea=w(),J=r(\"Safari\")&&!(w()||r(\"Coast\")||r(\"Opera\")||r(\"Edge\")||r(\"Silk\")||r(\"Android\"))&&!(v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\"));function K(a){return(a=a.exec(n))?a[1]:\"\"}(function(){if(ba)return K(/Firefox\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(y||z||x)return C;if(ea)return v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\")?K(/CriOS\\/([0-9.]+)/):K(/Chrome\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(J&&!(v()||r(\"iPad\")||r(\"iPod\")))return K(/Version\\/([0-9.]+)/);if(ca||da){var a=/Version\\/(\\S+).*Mobile\\/(\\S+)/.exec(n);if(a)return a[1]+\".\"+a[2]}else if(I)return(a=K(/Android\\s+([0-9.]+)/))?a:K(/Version\\/([0-9.]+)/);return\"\"})();var L,M=function(){if(!A)return!1;var a=d.Components;if(!a)return!1;try{if(!a.classes)return!1}catch(g){return!1}var b=a.classes,a=a.interfaces,e=b[\"@mozilla.org/xpcom/version-comparator;1\"].getService(a.nsIVersionComparator),c=b[\"@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1\"].getService(a.nsIXULAppInfo).version;L=function(a){e.compare(c,\"\"+a)};return!0}(),N=y&&!(8<=Number(G)),fa=y&&!(9<=Number(G));I&&M&&L(2.3);I&&M&&L(4);J&&M&&L(6);var ga={SCRIPT:1,STYLE:1,HEAD:1,IFRAME:1,OBJECT:1},O={IMG:\" \",BR:\"\\n\"};function P(a,b,e){if(!(a.nodeName in ga))if(3==a.nodeType)e?b.push(String(a.nodeValue).replace(/(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/g,\"\")):b.push(a.nodeValue);else if(a.nodeName in O)b.push(O[a.nodeName]);else for(a=a.firstChild;a;)P(a,b,e),a=a.nextSibling};function Q(a,b){b=b.toLowerCase();return\"style\"==b?ha(a.style.cssText):N&&\"value\"==b&&R(a,\"INPUT\")?a.value:fa&&!0===a[b]?String(a.getAttribute(b)):(a=a.getAttributeNode(b))&&a.specified?a.value:null}var ia=/[;]+(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(?:[^()]*\\([^()]*\\))*[^()]*$)/;\nfunction ha(a){var b=[];t(a.split(ia),function(a){var c=a.indexOf(\":\");0<c&&(a=[a.slice(0,c),a.slice(c+1)],2==a.length&&b.push(a[0].toLowerCase(),\":\",a[1],\";\"))});b=b.join(\"\");return b=\";\"==b.charAt(b.length-1)?b:b+\";\"}function S(a,b){N&&\"value\"==b&&R(a,\"OPTION\")&&null===Q(a,\"value\")?(b=[],P(a,b,!1),a=b.join(\"\")):a=a[b];return a}function R(a,b){b&&\"string\"!==typeof b&&(b=b.toString());return!!a&&1==a.nodeType&&(!b||a.tagName.toUpperCase()==b)}\nfunction T(a){return R(a,\"OPTION\")?!0:R(a,\"INPUT\")?(a=a.type.toLowerCase(),\"checkbox\"==a||\"radio\"==a):!1};var ja={\"class\":\"className\",readonly:\"readOnly\"},U=\"async autofocus autoplay checked compact complete controls declare defaultchecked defaultselected defer disabled draggable ended formnovalidate hidden indeterminate iscontenteditable ismap itemscope loop multiple muted nohref noresize noshade novalidate nowrap open paused pubdate readonly required reversed scoped seamless seeking selected spellcheck truespeed willvalidate\".split(\" \");function V(a,b){var e=null,c=b.toLowerCase();if(\"style\"==c)return(e=a.style)&&!f(e)&&(e=e.cssText),e;if((\"selected\"==c||\"checked\"==c)&&T(a)){if(!T(a))throw new h(15,\"Element is not selectable\");b=\"selected\";e=a.type&&a.type.toLowerCase();if(\"checkbox\"==e||\"radio\"==e)b=\"checked\";return S(a,b)?\"true\":null}var g=R(a,\"A\");if(R(a,\"IMG\")&&\"src\"==c||g&&\"href\"==c)return(e=Q(a,c))&&(e=S(a,c)),e;if(\"spellcheck\"==c){e=Q(a,c);if(null!==e){if(\"false\"==e.toLowerCase())return\"false\";if(\"true\"==e.toLowerCase())return\"true\"}return S(a,\nc)+\"\"}g=ja[b]||b;a:if(f(U))c=f(c)&&1==c.length?U.indexOf(c,0):-1;else{for(var u=0;u<U.length;u++)if(u in U&&U[u]===c){c=u;break a}c=-1}if(0<=c)return(e=null!==Q(a,b)||S(a,g))?\"true\":null;try{var k=S(a,g)}catch(ka){}(c=null==k)||(c=typeof k,c=\"object\"==c&&null!=k||\"function\"==c);c?e=Q(a,b):e=k;return null!=e?e.toString():null}var W=[\"_\"],X=d;W[0]in X||!X.execScript||X.execScript(\"var \"+W[0]);\nfor(var Y;W.length&&(Y=W.shift());){var Z;if(Z=!W.length)Z=void 0!==V;Z?X[Y]=V:X[Y]&&X[Y]!==Object.prototype[Y]?X=X[Y]:X=X[Y]={}};; return this._.apply(null,arguments);}.apply({navigator:typeof window!='undefined'?window.navigator:null,document:typeof window!='undefined'?window.document:null}, arguments);}\n).apply(null, arguments);", "args": [{"ELEMENT": "d4b51bfe-1d5e-4e54-878c-4f4509b0216b", "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf": "d4b51bfe-1d5e-4e54-878c-4f4509b0216b"}, "href"]}
2018-09-04 22:36:57 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:50910 "POST /session/7229021d-dce2-4653-bea9-7cd29732d83a/execute/sync HTTP/1.1" 200 150
2018-09-04 22:36:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2018-09-04 22:36:57 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE http://127.0.0.1:50910/session/7229021d-dce2-4653-bea9-7cd29732d83a/window {}
2018-09-04 22:37:00 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:50910 "DELETE /session/7229021d-dce2-4653-bea9-7cd29732d83a/window HTTP/1.1" 200 13
2018-09-04 22:37:00 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
Ad Count: 670
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be tough to guess the reason for the chunk of those messages, but from the logs it is pretty clear that:

- You have either configured the *WebDriver* instance to print the **`DEBUG`** messages on the console or it's the default configuration.
- This `click()` event of coarse triggers the execution of a **synchronous JavaScript** as:

  ```
  "POST /session/7229021d-dce2-4653-bea9-7cd29732d83a/execute/sync HTTP/1.1" 200 150
  ```
- Execution of the *JavaScript* is within the context of the currently selected frame or window.
- The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of an anonymous function.
- Within the script, use document to refer to the current document.
- Local variables will not be available once the script has finished executing, though global variables will persist.

### Conclusion

If you want to get rid of the **`DEBUG`** messages on the console you have to configure the *WebDriver* instance passing the *key*, *value* pair as follows:

```
browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe", log_level='TRACE', log_file='./Logs/IEDriver_Arg.log')
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not completely sure it's what you need, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226519/turning-off-logging-in-selenium-from-python) seems to be extremely similar to me. The difference is that logfile gets flooded and not the console.
In short, the solution is to raise the logging level of selenium by doing this:

```
# Set the threshold for selenium to WARNING
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER as seleniumLogger
seleniumLogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```