# Can't silence audio errors using Chromedriver with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a python script to scrape some webpages and am using selenium + chromedriver. The script is working fine and doing what it's meant to do without crashing, howver chromedriver is logging audio errors that I can't silence.

[image: Error Log]

I'm using log-level 3 so that only fatal errors should print, but I'm still getting the above. I also tried the option to disable logging and again I still got the same output as above.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
#options.add_argument('--disable-logging')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.get(link)
```

Any help to get round this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Just try using the `--mute-audio` argument this should disable the audio.

like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
# options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.get(link)
```

**EDIT:**

Try using [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels) (this is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688906/8179099)):

```
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER


LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
# options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.get(link)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still getting the same errors though

Comment: @Nik-D have you tried `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, service_log_path='NULL')`?

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion, just tried it but had no effect

Comment: @Nik-D sorry... :( in my last project we used `options.add_argument('--disable-logging')` and it worked I don't know why it dose not work for you...

Comment: @Nik-D try one last thing... see my edit it's using `logging`

Comment: Tried the edit you just posted as well, still no change :(

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!